# PHP regex help with replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I can't get this regex to work:

```
$string = 'blah blah |one|';
$search = array('/|one|/','/|two|/');
$string = preg_replace($search,"'<img src=\"\"'.str_replace('|','','\\0').'\".png\"/>'",$string);
```

I need it to return `blah blah <img src="one.png"/>` in this case, but having trouble dealing with the function inside the replacement.

Comment: You need to escape the pipe `|` character, so your regex should be `'/\|(one|two)\|/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason for this "function call" (which is just a string)? How about [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)? And you have to escape the `|`, because they are special characters ([alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)):

```
$string = 'blah blah |one|';
$search = array('/\\|(one)\\|/','/\\|(two)\\|/');
$string = preg_replace($search,'<img src="$1.png"/>',$string);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/BwP7xw0K)

Answer (score 1):

You can *capture* the name without the `|`s using parenthesis: `/\|(one)\|/`
Then you can reference the captured name using `$1` (instead of `$0`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work if what you want is put the text inside || as the source and also may have more than one image to convert on the same string:

```
<?php
    $string = 'blah blah |source| more blah blah |another| bye';
    $string = preg_replace('/\|([^\|]*)\|/',"<img src='$1.jpg' />",$string);
    var_dump($string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to over complicate it with the array replacement and inline function.

Simply capture the value between the pipes and use it directly.

```
preg_replace('/\|(one|two)\|/', '<img src="$1.png" />', $string);
```